# How to reach local server runing nightwatch tests against docker selenium and local app?

Tags: selenium, docker, nightwatch.js

#### Nightwatch

**nightwatch --version**

```
 v0.9.14
```

**config**

```
{
    "src_folders": [
        "test/e2e"
    ],
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false,
        "port": 4444
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "172.17.0.2",
            "silent": true
        },
        "dev": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome"
            },
            "globals": {
                "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Docker

**image**

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
8afbc5b1ee50        selenium/standalone-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_po..."   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:32770->4444/tcp   nightwatch-server
```

**network**

```
$ docker inspect nightwatch-server  --format "{{ json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}" | python -m json.tool
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "bridge": {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Aliases": null,
        "EndpointID": "7e621587f6ecbaa9b9d73aee601f647bebd76346b16d9d88e27c8ac7671e503d",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "Links": null,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "NetworkID": "363882b98acd8d8fb0756a296610a0135e3ebde4feae8bdceaa7917939d79752"
    }
}
```

#### Test

```
module.exports = {
    'index page': function (client) {
        client
            .url('http://localhost:8080')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .assert.title('Google')
            .end();
    }
};
```

#### Result

```
[Index] Test Suite
======================

Running:  index page
 ✔ Element <body> was visible after 100 milliseconds.                                                                                                                                                                                         ✖ Testing if the page title equals "Google".  - expected "Google" but got: "localhost"                                                                                                                                                          at Object.index page (/data/projects/apidae/frontend/static_src/test/e2e/index.js:6:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)


FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 1 passed (674ms)

 _________________________________________________
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 1 passed. (746ms)

 ✖ index

   - index page (674ms)
   Testing if the page title equals "Google".  - expected "Google" but got: "localhost"
       at Object.index page (/data/projects/apidae/frontend/static_src/test/e2e/index.js:6:12)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
```

#### Question

Why can't I reach my local server?

Comment: The output from Nightwatch suggests you can reach the server just fine, but the response isn't the markup you expect.  What do you get from: `docker exec nightwatch-server /bin/sh -c "curl http://localhost:8080"`

Comment: @JonathanRoss I got `Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... failed: Connection refused. failed: Cannot assign requested address`. To be clear the website is on my machine, the `standalone-chrome` is in the docker.